# net/http and ants gives me different result every run

Tags: go

I wrote a code to separate domains that give 200 responses and those that don't.
Although I have 3447 different domains, I get different results after each run of the program.

Source where i found domains: https://github.com/opendns/public-domain-lists/blob/master/opendns-random-domains.txt

`wc -l example.txt`
`3447`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/panjf2000/ants"
)

var sitelist []string

func check(pool interface{}) {
    address := pool.(string)
    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Timeout = time.Second * 5
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://"+address, nil)

    if response, err := client.Do(req); err == nil {
        status := response.StatusCode
        if status == 200 {
            // log.Println("Works:", address)
            sitelist = append(sitelist, "works:"+address)
            return
        }

        // log.Println("Not working:", address)
        sitelist = append(sitelist, "not-works:"+address)

    } else {
        // log.Println("Not working:", address)
        sitelist = append(sitelist, "not-works:"+address)

    }

}

func main() {

    defer ants.Release()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    p, _ := ants.NewPoolWithFunc(1000, func(i interface{}) {
        check(i)
        wg.Done()
    })
    defer p.Release()

    file, err := os.Open("example.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        a := scanner.Text()
        _ = p.Invoke(string(a))
    }

    wg.Wait()

    log.Println(len(sitelist))
}
```

`go run ./main.go`

> 3385

`go run ./main.go`

> 3338

`go run ./main.go`

> 3300

[And here is example.txt](https://pastebin.com/raw/Tk5b4TaW)

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. thank you

---

I noticed that when I want to use map, I get different errors.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/panjf2000/ants"
)

var (
    sitelist = make(map[string]int8)
)

func check(pool interface{}) {

    address := pool.(string)
    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Timeout = time.Second * 15

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://"+address, nil)
    if response, err := client.Do(req); err == nil {
        status := response.StatusCode
        if status == 200 {

            sitelist[string(address)] = 1

        } else {

            sitelist[string(address)] = 0
        }
    } else {

        sitelist[string(address)] = 0

    }

}

func main() {

    defer ants.Release()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    p, _ := ants.NewPoolWithFunc(1000, func(i interface{}) {
        check(i)
        wg.Done()
    })
    defer p.Release()
    file, err := os.Open("example.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        a := scanner.Text()
        _ = p.Invoke(string(a))
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(len(sitelist))

}
```

Output:

```
goroutine 4027 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002dff1c0}, {0x65d1b4, 0xf}, {0xc00073aa38, 0xc00003de10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002dff1c0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073aa38, 0xf})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002dff1c0}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc00073aa38, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc002a1b270, {0xc00035cc18, 0x13}, 0xc0014cfb80)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4028 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073aa38, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc00035cc18}, {0xc00073aa38, 0xc0014cfb80})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4053 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002f25140}, {0x65d1b4, 0xb}, {0xc000842f50, 0xc000040610})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002f25140}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc000842f50, 0xb})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002f25140}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc000842f50, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc002a97680, {0xc0006b2530, 0xf}, 0xc0014cfc30)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4054 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc000842f50, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc0006b2530}, {0xc000842f50, 0xc0014cfc30})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4029 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr(0x842360, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00173b4a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x10}, {0xc000842f60, 0xd})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:302 +0x5c7
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x6b87e8, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00173b4a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc000842f60, 0x10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288 +0x67a
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x872790, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00173b4a0}, {0x65d30e, 0x4}, {0x65d1b4, 0xc000718d80}, {0xc000842f60, 0x10}, {0x0, ...})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221 +0x41b
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc00002c2a0, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00173b4a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x7f61b406d4b8}, {0xc000842f60, 0x118})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:406 +0x448
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc00173b4a0, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00173b4a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x5dcff9}, {0xc000842f60, 0xc00181bd00})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1166 +0xda
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0x83cd80, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00173b4a0}, {{}, 0x0, {0xc00073aa80, 0x4}, {0xc000842f60, 0x10}, 0x0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1604 +0x845
net/http.(*Transport).dialConnFor(0xc00073aa38, 0xc0014cfd90)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1446 +0xb0
created by net/http.(*Transport).queueForDial
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1415 +0x3d7

goroutine 4040 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002cb8640}, {0x65d1b4, 0xf}, {0xc00073aa68, 0xc000033e10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002cb8640}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073aa68, 0xf})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002cb8640}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc00073aa68, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc0013fff90, {0xc00073b4a0, 0x13}, 0xc0014cfce0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4041 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073aa68, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc00073b4a0}, {0xc00073aa68, 0xc0014cfce0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4055 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr(0x842360, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001566720}, {0x65d1b4, 0x15}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x12})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:302 +0x5c7
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x6b87e8, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001566720}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x15})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288 +0x67a
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x872790, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001566720}, {0x65d30e, 0x4}, {0x65d1b4, 0xc00006e000}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x15}, {0x0, ...})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221 +0x41b
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc00002c2a0, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001566720}, {0x65d1b4, 0x7f61b417e378}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x118})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:406 +0x448
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc001566720, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001566720}, {0x65d1b4, 0x5dcff9}, {0xc0015462e8, 0xc0013d2c00})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1166 +0xda
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0x83cd80, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001566720}, {{}, 0x0, {0xc00047c160, 0x4}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x15}, 0x0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1604 +0x845
net/http.(*Transport).dialConnFor(0xc000842f50, 0xc000fff1e0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1446 +0xb0
created by net/http.(*Transport).queueForDial
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1415 +0x3d7

goroutine 4030 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002dff280}, {0x65d1b4, 0xd}, {0xc000842f60, 0xc00003de10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002dff280}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc000842f60, 0xd})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002dff280}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc000842f60, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc002a1b2c0, {0xc00035cc30, 0x11}, 0xc0014cfd90)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4031 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc000842f60, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc00035cc30}, {0xc000842f60, 0xc0014cfd90})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4042 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr(0x842360, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001eb28a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x12}, {0xc00073ad68, 0xf})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:302 +0x5c7
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x6b87e8, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001eb28a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073ad68, 0x12})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288 +0x67a
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x872790, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001eb28a0}, {0x65d30e, 0x4}, {0x65d1b4, 0xc0007193e0}, {0xc00073ad68, 0x12}, {0x0, ...})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221 +0x41b
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc00002c2a0, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001eb28a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x7f61b41711f8}, {0xc00073ad68, 0x118})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:406 +0x448
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc001eb28a0, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001eb28a0}, {0x65d1b4, 0x5dcff9}, {0xc00073ad68, 0xc00147a000})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1166 +0xda
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0x83cd80, {0x6b87e8, 0xc001eb28a0}, {{}, 0x0, {0xc000690840, 0x4}, {0xc00073ad68, 0x12}, 0x0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1604 +0x845
net/http.(*Transport).dialConnFor(0xc00073aa68, 0xc001ecc000)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1446 +0xb0
created by net/http.(*Transport).queueForDial
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1415 +0x3d7

goroutine 4032 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr(0x842360, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00159cf00}, {0x65d1b4, 0x13}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:302 +0x5c7
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x6b87e8, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00159cf00}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x13})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/ipsock.go:288 +0x67a
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x872790, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00159cf00}, {0x65d30e, 0x4}, {0x65d1b4, 0xc0003a6b60}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x13}, {0x0, ...})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:221 +0x41b
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0xc00002c2a0, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00159cf00}, {0x65d1b4, 0x7f61b406d4b8}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x118})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/dial.go:406 +0x448
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc00159cf00, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00159cf00}, {0x65d1b4, 0x5dcff9}, {0xc0000bea38, 0xc0015bb800})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1166 +0xda
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0x83cd80, {0x6b87e8, 0xc00159cf00}, {{}, 0x0, {0xc0003c0750, 0x4}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x13}, 0x0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1604 +0x845
net/http.(*Transport).dialConnFor(0xc000842f60, 0xc001379970)
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1446 +0xb0
created by net/http.(*Transport).queueForDial
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1415 +0x3d7

goroutine 4056 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002f25200}, {0x65d1b4, 0x12}, {0xc0015462e8, 0xc000040610})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002f25200}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x12})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002f25200}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc002a976d0, {0xc000690f00, 0x16}, 0xc000fff1e0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4057 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0015462e8, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc000690f00}, {0xc0015462e8, 0xc000fff1e0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4043 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002cb8700}, {0x65d1b4, 0xf}, {0xc00073ad68, 0xc000033e10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002cb8700}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073ad68, 0xf})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002cb8700}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc00073ad68, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc002ce2000, {0xc00073b4b8, 0x13}, 0xc001ecc000)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4033 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP({0x6b8778, 0xc002dff340}, {0x65d1b4, 0x10}, {0xc0000bea38, 0xc00003de10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:231 +0x1b7
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x842360, {0x6b8778, 0xc002dff340}, {0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x10})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:97 +0x128
net.glob..func1({0x6b8778, 0xc002dff340}, 0x0, {0x65d1b4, 0x0}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x5ea7d0})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/hook.go:23 +0x3d
net.(*Resolver).lookupIPAddr.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/lookup.go:296 +0x9f
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x842370, 0xc002a1b310, {0xc00035cc48, 0x14}, 0xc001379970)
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x3b
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
        /usr/lib/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2f1

goroutine 4044 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc00073ad68, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc00073b4b8}, {0xc00073ad68, 0xc001ecc000})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4066 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0000bea38, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc00035cc48}, {0xc0000bea38, 0xc001379970})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 4001 [chan send]:
net.acquireThread()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/net.go:675 +0x45
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME({0x65d1b4, 0x3}, {0xc0005908e0, 0x4})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:146 +0x85
net.cgoIPLookup(0x842370, {0x65d1b4, 0xc0005908f0}, {0xc0005908e0, 0xc0020ec420})
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:220 +0x3b
created by net.cgoLookupIP
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:230 +0x125

goroutine 1744 [select]:
net.(*netFD).connect.func2()
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:119 +0x9e
created by net.(*netFD).connect
        /usr/lib/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:118 +0x385
exit status 2
...
```

Comment: A quick look at ants docs showed, that there is an expiryDuration of 1 second. Also, your list is not thread safe.

Comment: The timeout of 5 seconds in the client may also cause trouble. I have definitely seen sites, that take around that time to answer

Comment: I tried different timeouts but the result is still the same. Also why is my list not thread safe?

Comment: You've added part of a stack trace without the actual error message, but I assume it's a "concurrent use of map" fatal error. You cannot have multiple goroutines writing to the same data structure concurrently. Even if your timeouts are sufficient, and every request responds identically every time, and the failure to read and close the responses doesn't cause any problems, you still have a data race.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with the answers given, I understood that there is a data race case.

I solved it with an external function with sync.Mutex

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/panjf2000/ants"
)

var (
    sitelist = make(map[string]int8)
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var m sync.Mutex

func add(address string, status int8, m *sync.Mutex) {
    m.Lock()
    sitelist[address] = status
    m.Unlock()
}

func check(pool interface{}) {
    address := pool.(string)

    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Timeout = time.Second * 45

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://"+address, nil)

    if response, err := client.Do(req); err == nil {

        status := response.StatusCode
        if status == 200 {

            add(address, 1, &m)

        } else {

            add(address, 0, &m)

        }
    } else {
        add(address, 0, &m)

    }

}

func main() {

    defer ants.Release()
    p, _ := ants.NewPoolWithFunc(1000, func(i interface{}) {
        check(i)
        wg.Done()
    })

    defer p.Release()
    file, err := os.Open("example.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        a := scanner.Text()
        wg.Add(1)
        _ = p.Invoke(string(a))

    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(len(sitelist))

}
```